# Проверка города и страны, pyowm (python open weather map )

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, openweathermap, pyowm

Пишу телеграмм бота, который показывает погоду. Сделал регистрацию пользователя, но я не совсем понимаю, как проверить на правильность написания название города и страны, для того что бы потом уже искать по этим данным погоду. Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fp5-XQFr_nk&t=2348s
тайм код: 45:00

Comment: daladn0, я посмотрел видео, но не понял чем это поможет. Парень просто скопировал код из документации, никаких проверок нет. Если не совсем понятно в чем сложность, это в том, что сервис openweathermap может показать погоду Москвы, но погоду не нашей Москвы, что в России. Я бы хотел уточнять запрос, для более правильного получения погоды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создай хендлер с типом location и попроси пользователя отправить геопозицию, из полученных данных доставай широту и долготу. Отправляй запрос к open weaher map с указанием широты и долготы. Остается только распарсить ответ

```
import requests

def get_city(lat, lon):
    url = f"http://api.openweathermap.org/geo/1.0/direct?lat={lat}&lon={lon}&limit=1"
    api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"
    headers = {"Accept": "application/json"}
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params={"appid": api_key})
    data = response.json()
```